# Select2 jQuery and Rails ajax form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using the jQuery select2 plugin in my Rails4 app.

The plugin is working for me in forms that are not using ajax. But, for ajax forms I don't know how to do it.

There's a form inside a bootstrap 3 modal, here's how I load the same:

```
<%= link_to t(:new), new_address_path, remote: true, :class => 'btn btn-info'  %>

$('<%= j render "form", title: "#{t(:address)}" %>').modal();
```

How can I initialise the select2 plugin for the selects inside this form?

Answer (score 1):

Did I understand it correctly? The form is a modal which is not displayed on the page at first but after some user interactions. In that case the on document ready will not find the element to activate select2. I would suggest to either use the [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) plugin which observes DOM changes, e.g.

```
$('form.modal').livequery('.controls select', 
  function(elem){
    $(elem).select2(); 
})
```

Or you can also put what @Willem suggested into a javascript tag in the html partial of the form modal.

Comment: I have tried this approach, it is almost working. It creates the select2 input, but is not usable. I guess, the plugin is trying to be initialised in a select that is not yet completely populated.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using `javascript`:

```
// On document ready
$(function(){

  $(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function() {
    // Activate select2 after ajax request
    activateJSPlugins();
  });

  activateJSPlugins();
});

function activateJSPlugins()  {
  // Find all dropdowns and initialize select2
  $(".controls select").each(function() {

    // Initialize select2
    $(this).select2();
  });
}
```

`$(".controls select")` would be the `css` selector you apply to find your select2 controls.

**EDIT**

> /app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap_and_overrides.js

Create a `bootstrap_and_overrides.js` file.

> /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap_and_overrides
```

Then this code will run for all your selec2 inputs

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do this in the form generated dynamically from an Ajax request?